# Insert html after

Tags: jquery, html, insert, load

My question is the following:

What would be the best way to insert a `<div>` container, and the next one after the last inserted one?

```
<div class="pane">
    <div class="inhoud">
        <h3>Sample heading</h3>
        <p>Testbericht.</p>
    </div>
    <form id="noteform" class="frm">
        <input type="image" src="images/kn_verwijder.gif" alt="delete" class="delete" />
        <br />
        <input type="hidden" name="frmnoteid" id="frmnoteid" value="" />
    </form>
</div>
```

What I know so far:

- Counting the number of divs already on the page with `$("#foo > div").size()`
  and the `.insertAfter()` method.
- Using the selector and the `.load()` method to load the html data from a file.

The problem is that I don't know if I can use these methods properly to get the result.

If anybody has already had any experience with these?

Answer (score 0):

you can use `$(".divtogoafter:last").append("content to insert");`   That uses the psuedo-selector last, so that the last div is the one that the data is inserted after.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really clear about what you're trying to do, but you could do something like this...

Instead of using load(), use $.get() to load the html without inserting it, and then append it into the page using the sucess callback. That way, you don't need to worry about creating a wrapper div. Just have your html page, tbnote.html, have the proper markup you would like.

```
function newnote() {
    $.get("tbnote.html", function(html) {
        if($(.pane).length > 0) { \\test  there is already .pane div on page
            $(".pane:last").after(html);
        } else {
            $("#someOtherDiv").append(html); \\append to another div
        }
    });
}
```

[after()](http://docs.jquery.com/Manipulation/after#content) will parse the html response and inject it into the dom, well, after the selected element.

With [$.get](http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax/jQuery.get#urldatacallbacktype), you could also do something more advanced and have your template be able to accept querystrings, or data, and plug it into your html before rendering the page.